# try to get float or integer values stored in session

Tags: java, jsp, session

I have stored in two different attribute two integer value

```
session.setAttribute("passengers", new Integer(passengers))
session.setAttribute("luggages", new Integer(luggages));
```

but when I try to get them in a next request through

```
Integer passengers = (Integer) session.getAttribute("passengers")
Integer luggages = (Integer) session.getAttribute("luggages");
```

I get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: Show us the full stack trace, give us more context.

Comment: Looks like you added these session attributes as `String` somewhere else in your code.

Comment: you might be setting it from some other place as a String

Comment: Where this code is written in Servlet or JSP?

Comment: Show us the full stack trace and the line specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
int passengers = Integer.parseInt((String) session.getAttribute("passengers"))
int luggages = Integer.parseInt((String)session.getAttribute("luggages"));
```

Comment: I don't think so that this will solve the issue because `getAttribute`  must return `Integer` Object not `String` object as per OP code. by the way `getAttribute()` return type is `Object`.

Comment: @Mazzy just few seconds back you said it works and now you are saying its now working.

Comment: I posted all the code...I explain here it. In the first request conferm I save the values. In the request commit I get the values from the session but there I get the error